# не корректно работает шара для facebook

Tags: php, массивы, facebook

Всем привет! Подскажите пож как можно поправить FB? Есть array с параметрами(который работает хорошо, о чем свидетельствует хорошая работа шары на VK) и foreach, VK работает хорошо - все выводит как надо,  FB работает не корректно, а картинку и вовсе не выводит:

```
{$params = [

'url'=>"http://`$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST|escape``$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|escape`",

'title' => $product->name|escape,

'description' => $product->meta_description|escape,

'image' => $product->image->filename|resize:200:200
                ]}

{foreach [

'vk-icon-lg' => "https://vk.com/share.php?url=`$params.url`&title=`$params.title`&description=`$params.description`&image=`$params.image`&noparse=true",

'fb-icon-lg' => "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=`$params.description`&p%5Bsummary%5D=`$params.title`&p%5Burl%5D=`$params.url`&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=`$params.image`"

                ] as $item}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение!
В текущем файле изменяем foreach на:

{foreach [

'vk-icon-lg' => "https://vk.com/share.php?url=`$params.url`&title=`$params.title`&description=`$params.description`&image=`$params.image`&noparse=true",

'fb-icon-lg' => "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=`$params.url`"

```
            ] as $item}
```

а также в индексном файле пишем "мета tags":

meta property="og:url" content="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST|escape}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|escape}"/>

meta property="og:title" content="{$product->name|escape}"/>

meta property="og:description" content="{$product->meta_description|escape}" />

meta property="og:image" content="{$product->image->filename|resize:200:200}" />

После этих манипуляций все работает хорошо.